# Is there a way to make an IPhone wallpaper react to touch event?(programmatically)

Tags: iphone, wallpaper

Like [Nexus Revamped](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stealthcopter.nexusrevamped&hl=en) does. What kind of tech is involved in this? Can I do this via Javascript&CSS? If it's not possible, please explain why?

Edit(1): what I want to do is to make a animated wallpaper([a Kaleidoscope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaleidoscope#History)) spinning while user swiping on the screen.